# $O\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)+O(1)=O(1)$?

Tags: solution-verification, asymptotics

Intuitively I think the question posed in the title is rather obvious. That is, at least when $x>1$ then $O\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)+O(1)$ is bounded by some constant times $1$, $\forall x$.

But how would you prove the statement in the title? I tried using a working definition that I found on a youtube lecture: If $f$ and $g$ are functions that take on positive values, defined for all $x$ in some set $S$. then we say $f$ is $O(g)$ and write $f(x)=O(g(x))$ if there exists a constant $K$ such that $f(x)\le K\cdot g(x)$, $\forall x\in S$.

I tried the following: Let $f_{1}(x)=O(1/x)$ and $f_{2}(x)=O(1)$. Then we know that $f_{1}(x)\le K_{1}\cdot 1/x$ and in particular $$f_{1}(x)\le K_{1}\cdot 1/x < K_{1}\cdot 1$$ $\forall x>1$. We also know that $f_{2}(x)\le K_{2}\cdot 1$, which implies that $$f_{1}(x)+f_{2}(x)\le K_{1}\cdot 1/x + K_{2}\cdot 1\le K_{1}\cdot 1+K_{2}\cdot 1 = K\cdot 1$$ $\forall x>1$. thus $$f_{1}(x)+f_{2}(x)=O(1)$$ $\forall x>1$. Meaning $$O(1/x)+O(1)=O(1).$$

Comment: Looks good to me! In fact, this same proof shows that $O \left ( \frac{1}{x} \right ) \leq O(1)$ on $x > \epsilon$ for any (constant!) positive $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to your correct proof, which gives $O\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)+O(1)\subset O(1)$, statement in title can be proved in reverse direction also i.e. when we understand "$=$" as equality between sets.

Assume $f\in O(1)$ and consider $f=\frac{1}{x}+f-\frac{1}{x}$. Now first summand is in $O(\frac{1}{x})$ and for second works same way as in your proof, so, $f(x)-\frac{1}{x}\in O(1)$ for $x \gt 1$. We obtain $O(1) \subset O\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)+O(1)$, so, obtain statement in title:
$$O\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)+O(1)=O(1)$$